# Bootstrap - Cannot override property of pseudo-class

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I'm basically trying to accomplish a hover effect. I can't seem to override using the properties of the pseudo-class in the following code:

CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        li:hover
        {
            color: #000000 !important;
            background-color: #ff8c00;
        }
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
            <nav class="navbar-inverse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-justified" style="font-size: 1.3em;">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </nav>
```

If I remove the the `nav` class from the `ul` element, the hover feature works fine, but the structure looks really ugly. How can I get this to work?

Update:

Uploaded my code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abs0lut3_z3r0/vfanpb6v/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the css like this:

```
  <style type="text/css">
        .nav>li>a:hover
        {
            color: #000000;
            background-color: #ff8c00;
        }
    </style>
```

This way, the class `nav` with the immediately nested child `li` and  `a` tag with the  pseudoclass `:hover` will be selected and the bootstrap-standard will be overridden.

Comment: The 'active' class doesn't seem to work as well. Any idea what I can do there?

Comment: try ".active a" to specify that

Comment: I was referring to using the 'active' class from bootstrap.

Comment: oh sorry. you could use javascript for setting the 'active' on the correct element, or write it directly in the code. (if you meant that)

Comment: sorry again, I misunderstood.... try add ".nav-justified>.active", so the active class will be the same style as the :hover effect

Answer (score 0):

The active class won't work because the rules are only specified on `:hover`
To apply styles on active as well you will have to call the CSS on active class as well

```
.nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:active
{
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ff8c00;
}
```